# How to create a Spring ModelAndView from html String?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am fetching an external webpage (as a string) from my Controller. How can I return this string, containing HTML, as a `ModelAndView`?

Comment: Sorry but don't you think your question in that form is a bit confusing ?

Comment: ? What is confusing, I ll try to explain? I have String that contains html and I want to return it from my Controller in form of a ModelAndView.

Comment: Just stream it out, by taking a HttpServletResponse as a parameter and writing to the outputstream that you can get from that, raw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to return that webpage to the client/browser then you do not need to create a ModelAndView.

Instead do this

```
@Controller
public class MyController() {

    @RequestMapping(...)
    @ResponseBody
    public String controllerMethod() {
        String htmlDocument = getHtmlFromSomeWhere();
        return htmlDocument;
    }
}
```

---

If you have to return a `ModelAndView` the you have to write you own `View` implementation.
Have a look at `AbstractPdfView` for some template.

```
return ModelAndView(new MyPlainHtmlView(htmlDocument));


public class MyPlainHtmlView implements View {
     ....

     private final String htmlDocument;

     public MyPlainHtmlView(String htmlDocument) {
         this.htmlDocument = htmlDocument;
     }

     @Override
     renderMergedOutputModelMap<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
           ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
           out.write(this.htmlDocument.getBytes("utf-8"));
     }
}
```